# How do I minimize opencv build after installation?

Tags: opencv, installation, cmake, build

It's been a long time since I last built opencv, contrib and all. The last installation I did, I recall being able to shrink the size of the installation after it was done; presently the file "build" is 28 gigabytes. My previous installation was able to be reduced in size to about 12 gigabytes after installation by removing files that are only necessary for installing and building, but not running. I have since forgotten what these files are that can be removed, and the installation tutorial that told me which ones were able to be removed. Can some shed some light on which files in my build folder can be removed after my release and debug builds have been installed?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to extract the "bin/ include/ lib/ share/" QUAD and remove the entire cmake build tree, there is a simple thing you can do:

```sh
cd /path/to/cv/build
DESTDIR=/tmp/lalala make install -j7
```

Then you'll find what the QUAD in `/tmp/lalala/path/to/your/original/install/dir`. If that's all you need, `rm -rf /path/to/cv/build`.

If you are not using Linux/Unix & make however, let me know in the comment and I'll edit the answer.

Love your spiderman movies, btw. :-)

Comment: I'm running on Windows at the moment. I did the standard make/build/install process, and have left with a lot of residuals. I have a C:/opencv folder where everything is kept, including the build folder. I know that the files used for the build can be deleted, as I have deleted them and everything is working fine still, but I'm very hesitant to delete anything inside the actual build folder. Glad you like the movies as well :)

Comment: @TomHolland Unless I'm very wrong, if you've already installed, the bin/include/lib/share in the install dir is all you need. Also, it doesn't hurt to first try putting the build dir in Recycle bin for a while and test for a while to see if everything is still fine, if you wanna be on the safe side.